# Digital sign performance issue

Tags: java, digital-signature, pkcs#11, xml-signature

I am currently stuck in a performance issue about digital signature. The scenario is the following: There are up to 2000 files that need to be signed and each one of them need to be signed a hundred times, not the whole file but chunks of it. To do so I'm using Apache Santuario and SUNPKCS11 class and API. The certificate is A3, which means Token or SmartCard devices. I tried both of them, SmartCard and Token, but they're extremely slow to sign, even tough I used parallel processing. SmartCard is signing a hundred percent better than Token. It takes 30 seconds per file, and 70, respectively. I have no clue of why it's taking so long, does anyone have any idea to help me?
By the way, Token seems not to accept parallel signature, once it starts to throw exception randomly while signing the hundred chunks of a file, but it's slower even when signing sincronally.

Comment: 30 seconds for 100 signatures (1 file) is 0,3'' per signature. It is not a bad time for a smartcard. What is the medium size of a chunk? Why you sign each chunk instead of the complete file ? (You can calculate the digest incrementally if you have a size problem)

Comment: The chunk is something about 2kb, once the whole file has 200kb. I can't sign the complete file 'cause it's not on my hands.These files are submitted to a government system, they expect a hundred signed chunks, may be 'cause they're gonna split and process it as there was no relationship between them, well, actually there is not, they're just kinda compressed together to make submition easier. I guess there's no way I could sign them at the same time, is there? I agree about 300ms being a pretty nice time, but I just can't sign the hundred on that time, would it be possible? I wish so.

Comment: It is possible, but you would need dedicated HSM hardware with cryptographic acceleration. The number of operations per second will be límited by the size of the key and the signature algorithm. For example this one probably meets your requirements https://safenet.gemalto.com/data-encryption/hardware-security-modules-hsms/pci-hsm/

Comment: I would really like to understand it better so I could argue with client about it, 'cause they have got a Safenet 5100 and I have no arguments to tell them why it's slower than the SmartCard, do you have any idea? I'm afraid they will buy a different hardware and it's not going to make much difference, that happened to this, I thought and read token would be better so I told them to get it, and it performed worse. The algorithm is rsa-sha256. Thank you so much buddy!

Comment: Safenet 5100 is not an HSM with acceleration. It is a double factor authenticator for final users and it is not designed to perform massive processes of digital signature. Why it should be faster than the smartcard? You have tested it and measure the results, so you now know the real performance